# Magento 1.9 : Hide specific submenu

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I need help to modify a menu.

The problem is that I want submenu to be available on one category. But on the other top menus categories they should not show in the drop down from the top menu

(I can not disable them because they are in use in the sidebar navigation).

In the menu file for my theme this is the code:

```
<div class="nav-container">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
                <?php echo $_menu ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="sf-menu-block">
                <div id="menu-icon"><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></div>
                <ul class="sf-menu-phone">
                    <?php echo $_menu ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I have also tried to modify Navigation.php with no success. My Magento knowledge is not 100%.

I have search forums but can not find exactly what I need. Any guidance would be appreciated.

**=> EDIT:**

Can it be in this file navigation.php?

```
    public function getCurrentChildCategories()
{
    if (null === $this->_currentChildCategories) {
        $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
        $category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
        $this->_currentChildCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
        $productCollection->addCountToCategories($this->_currentChildCategories);
    }
    return $this->_currentChildCategories;
}
```

Comment: Set the flag "Include in Navigation Menu " to "No" on the categories you don't want in the menu.

Comment: Thanks. But this will not help me because then the sub menu will also be disabled in my sidebar menu I have on each page.

Comment: @user20309 that's not true, that are two different things. It will always be included in the left menu. The option is specific for the navigation menu(if your theme supports it_

Comment: Allright, thank you for the information. Then I will focus on the sidebar extension that removes the subfolders when they are not active. WIll update you when I got better knowledge about the script!

Comment: I changed the css file instead of the other files to hide the specific sub menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide it in the Navigation then see the image

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this will not help me because then the sub menu will also be disabled in my sidebar menu I have on each page.

Comment: I changed the css file instead of the other files to hide the specific sub menus.